# Repeating flutter implicit animations

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I have combined a bunch of implicit animations ( viz. AnimatedContainer, AnimatedPositioned, etc) to create an entirely new Animated Object.
I needed to run it in repeat mode.
The animation controller was out of the option, cause of implicit animation.
I am currently using Timer (provided by dart) to implement the same.

My question is -

1. Is there a better way to repeat the animations, implement vsync, and if possible any other performance optimization, without disturbing the Animated Object?

Platform - Flutter-web only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget/onEnd.html

Comment: This made my code a bit cleaner. Thanks @pskink